# How to keep image scale during resize

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have a sample html page with a list build with semantic ui.
When I try to resize my browser window a list item with bigger description makes the image smaller(screenshot).

ps. I dont have this problem with twitter bootstrap.

**up**
I didn't change much css just added this to custom.css

```
.ui.tiny.images img, .ui.tiny.image { width:30px;}
```

one of the items:

```
<div class="sixteen wide column ">
  <div class="ui divided small  list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="ui tiny image " src="examples/images/207664bebf8011e1a9f71231382044a1_7.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <a class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, quod, culpa voluptatem illo cupiditate error in minus eveniet ut impedit? Quo quia inventore assumenda </a>
        <span class="ui mini horizontal label">6.12.2014 | Comments: 10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry... what exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @canon Look at the screen. I want the first image to be the same size as the others during resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the default max-width property.

it used to be `max-width: 100%;` by default

now I have this:

```
.ui.tiny.images img, .ui.tiny.image {
   width:32px;
   max-width: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Is how bootstrap handles it. Consider making a similar implementation.